# how to attach framing to this window in concrete?

Tags: basement, windows, framing

I'm looking to finish my basement. I have several windows embedded in the concrete as shown in the picture below. I was planning to put framing up in front of the concrete and run some plywood all around the window frame with some concrete anchors drilled through the window frame. Is that right? What is the right way to attach wooden framing to the window frame pictured below?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using treated lumber, you can attach the framing using a combination of suitable adhesive and concrete anchors like tapcons.

Consider, though, whether you'll have moisture issues between your plywood (or finished surface) and the concrete. How do you plan to seal and insulate, or do you?

Comment: I would definitely like to know that my lower third is sealed, should any water happen to collect in the window well. I'll have to look for some suitable glue for sticking wood onto that metal window frame.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a cold climate, keep in mind you will want insulation.

Also need to consider issues of condensation or wicking.

You will want a moisture and vapour barrier between any wood and concrete. Also consider foam insulation between metal and wood to avoid moisture from condensation when water vapour in the air meets cold metal.

Other than that there are lots of different adhesives or fasteners you could use. Go shopping and get whatever you want.

Comment: Foam between concrete and the framing.

Comment: Yes, that is ideal, because it can be a moisture barrier, vapour barrier and insulation all in one.

Comment: Alternatively, frame it with vinyl instead of wood.